# Mac OS X keeps "old" environment variable around

Tags: macos, mac, bash, path, environment-variables

So far I had `/Applications/play-1.2.5/` added to my $PATH variable. Now I'm working with 2.2.1, which I installed in `/Applications/play-2.2.1` and changed in `~/.bash_profile` (which is getting sourced at startup). However, when printing $PATH, 1.2.5 is somehow still around:

```
mbp:~ user$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/share/npm/bin:/Applications/play-2.2.1:/usr/local/heroku/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Applications/play-1.2.5:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/:/opt/X11/bin
```

As far as I now, I only entered $PATH variables in `.bash_profile`, which looks like this:

```
mbp:~ user$ cat .bash_profile 
source ~/.git-completion.bash

### Added by the Heroku Toolbelt
export PATH="/usr/local/heroku/bin:$PATH"


### Play Framework
export PATH="/Applications/play-2.2.1:$PATH"


export PATH="/usr/local/share/npm/bin:$PATH"
```

I'm also not sure where the XAMPP extension to the variable comes from. Can I see somewhere which other files are being sourced on startup?

Comment: Have you looked in `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` and `/etc/bashrc`, as well?

Comment: Yes, not one of those three files contains anything related to Xampp or Play 1.2.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution - I had edited the `/private/etc/paths` file at some point and added the paths there. I don't know why I put it in those files in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Editing a file does not change the value of a variable in an existing shell session. The file is only read to initialize the environment; it is not consulted every time the value of the variable is requested. If you start a new shell, the value of `PATH` will be taken from your modified file. In the existing shell, try running `source .bash_profile` to re-evaluate the file and update your shell's environment.

Comment: I've actually tried restarting a couple of times so it should most definitely be gone by then. Thanks though!

Comment: I misread your question. Adding a new directory to the beginning of `PATH` doesn't remove a similar directory later in the path; it just prevents identically named binaries in the later directory from being found by the lookup algorithm (which looks in each directory in order until a match ends the search).

Answer (score 1):

If you're running Mac OS X 10.6.8 or earlier and if you're late on a few security patches, you may have variables in ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist
Since then, variables may be stored in /private/etc/launchd.conf

Comment: Neither file exists. I'm running the latest Maverick with all patches.

Comment: In that case, you will have to create /private/etc/launchd.conf (which doesn't exist by default)

Answer (score 0):

@Xymak1y suggested editing `/private/etc/paths` however this is not recommended, instead place a file into `/private/etc/pahts.d/` containing the lines you want to add to your `$PATH`.